# Google chrome theme: modifying the download section color

Tags: json, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-theme

I have created my custom google chrome theme. Everything seems fine until I downloaded a file. The download section at the bottom of the page is white and the text is white. Only icon are visible

[image]

How can I modified either the color of the text only in the download section (I need white text in my tab/bookmar) or the background of the download secttion.

My manifest.json:

```
{

"manifest_version": 2,

"version": "1.0",

"name": "My Theme",

"theme": {

"images" : {

"theme_frame" : "images/frame.png",

"theme_toolbar" : "images/toolbar.png",

"theme_ntp_background" : "images/background.png",

"theme_tab_background" : "images/tab.png"

},

"colors" : {

"ntp_link": [255,255,255],

"ntp_text": [255,255,255],

"ntp_section_link": [255,255,255],

"ntp_section_text": [255,255,255],

"ntp_background": [255,255,255],

"frame": [255,255,255],

"toolbar": [255,255,255],

"tab_text": [255,255,255],

"tab_background_text": [255,255,255],

"bookmark_text": [255,255,255]

},

"tints" : {

"buttons" : [1,1,1]

},

"properties" : {

"ntp_background_alignment" : "bottom",

"ntp_background_repeat": "repeat"

}

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing to `"toolbar": [128,128, 128]`